# How to get Spring Data to read documents from Mongo that don't have _class attributes

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

MongoTemplate inserts an attribute named "_class" into anything it puts into Mongo, and there are ways to turn that off.

However, it seems to be unwilling to read anything back out of it that doesn't have a _class attribute.  Simply removing that from the mongo document appears to make it inaccessible.  Since reading data you didn't write yourself is an obvious use case, I figure I must be missing something here.

I've been attempting to use this:

```
List<SomeClass> list = mongoTemplate.findAll(SomeClass.class, "someCollection");
```

...where SomeClass is annotated with @Id and @Document, and the documents in someCollection  otherwise correctly map to the object.  I can verify this by creating one of these objects in code, using insert to get it into Mongo, and then see that I can read it back out again.

This works just fine if _class is there but fails if it is not.  I do not care about polymorphism or anything that might actually need this attribute.  How can I get MongoTemplate to read data that it didn't itself write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer...DavidA's advice was correct but missing the crucial part: when you set up the MappingMongoConverter dealio with the null type mapping business, it not only stops writing the "_class" pollution, but also stops attempting to read it.  This causes it to fall back to the type you provide when attempting to retrieve your documents from Mongo.

I haven't seen anywhere that anyone actually mentions that.  :)

So, for anybody else running into this issue, here's the XML configuration I used (adapted from something I found somewhere else here on StackOverflow, but I lost the link, sorry):

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" dbname="${mongo.dbname}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter" />
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoMappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

<bean id="mongoConverter" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mongoMappingContext" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="mongoTypeMapper"></property>
</bean>
```

And then in the Java code:

```
//build query object
UnifiedProduct mpp = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, UnifiedProduct.class, "collection-name");
```

...which results in the UnifiedProduct class I wanted, and no annoying "_class" pollution.

Comment: Nice.  Good to know.  I was about to post a comment about trying explicit converters, but this is a more general solution.  Thanks for coming back and posting the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `MappingMongoConverter` uses a `MongoTypeMapper` in order to figure out what type to use when reading in a DBObject from the database.  The `DefaultMongoTypeMapper` uses the `"_class"` attribute to work as you have described.

You should be able to implement your own `MongoTypeMapper` and tell the `MappingMongoConberter` to use it.  Your version can use other indicators instead of `"_class"` value to determine what type should be created when reading.

Comment: DavidA: Thanks for responding.  This sounds like the answer is that it can't.  I'm a little confused over that - I'm telling it explicitly what class I want it to use ("SomeClass.class" in the above snippet) so I don't get why it is the spring-data-mongo stuff would be designed this way, particularly when other NoSQL and/or JSON mapping implementations don't have this limitation.

I guess I'll try making a MongoTypeMapper that always uses the single type I care about and see if that works.